# Capture the call stack quickly

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to capture the call stack as quickly as possible. Right now this is what I've got:

```
void* addrs[10] = {};
DWORD hash;
RtlCaptureStackBackTrace(0, 10, addrs, &hash);

for( size_t i = 0; i <10; ++i )
{
    std::cout << addrs[i] << '\n';
}
```

This is for use in a memory tracking system, so it's perfectly fine that I end up with an array of addresses if they can later (upon some user driven event) be turned into something human readable.

- <strike>How can I turn `addrs` into something human readable?</strike> (see edit below)
- **Is there anything faster than `RtlCaptureStackBackTrace`?**
- Is there a cross platform way to capture the call stack?

**Edit:**

I turned the addresses into human readable information by using `SymFromAddr` and `SymGetLineFromAddr64`. However, my version of `new` that uses `CaptureStackBackTrace` takes ~30x longer than the original and almost all that time is because of the stack trace. I'm still looking for a faster solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a cross platform way to capture the call stack?

The quick answer is that unfortunately it's not possible.  Different compilers and platforms will organize the stack differently, and without "help" from the compiler, you're not going to be able to accurately trace back through the stack ... the most you could do on platforms that are using a stack-frame base-pointer would be to move up the stack using the values in either `EBP` or `RBP`, and even that is dependent on if you're running a 32-bit x86 executable, or a x86_64 executable.  Additionally the rules governing the UNIX application-binary-interface (ABI) and the Windows ABI are completely different.  So in general, you're going to end up having to support at least four different possibilities:

1. Unix 32-bit ABI
2. Unix 64-bit ABI
3. Windows 32-bit ABI
4. Windows 64-bit ABI

Keep in mind that the UNIX 64-bit ABI allows for compilers to choose whether they will or will not support a stack-frame base-pointer ... so the use of a base-pointer is not guaranteed; a compiler may simply choose to reference all stack-variables against the stack-pointer itself without using a separate base-pointer. That would still be considered compliant with the UNIX 64-bit ABI.

So as you can see, with all these possible variations, you're going to have a very tough time making a reliable cross-platform stack-tracer.  Your best-bet it to use the tools available to you for the platform you're targeting.  If you need to support multiple platforms, then unfortunately there's going to be some level of code duplication as you utlize platform-specific tools to help you reliably perform the stack-trace.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a cross-platform way, but there are cross-platform libraries that do the trick.  [It's a common requirement for garbage collectors](http://blog.mozilla.com/jorendorff/2007/08/09/conservative-stack-scanning-101/).

Unfortunately, I don't know enough about these libraries to recommend one.  MMgc has something embedded (explained in the link, above).  I'm sure Hans Boehm's garbage collector has another.

These libraries, in general, will rely on platform-specific calls, such as `RtlCaptureStackBacktrace` on Windows.  I would be amazed if any such library went faster than the platform-specific calls; but I would also be amazed if any such library went significantly slower.  The only question -- to me -- would be whether you prefer to call the Windows API call directly or to route that call through another library.